# Goldstone boson-Gauge boson coupling in the Glashow-Weinberg-Salam (GWS) model

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, standard-model, gauge-theory, higgs

In the GWS model it is expected to see terms like $\sim gv\partial_\mu \phi W^\mu$, where $g$ is a coupling constant, $v$ the VEV of the Higgs field, $\phi$ a Goldstone boson, and $W$ a gauge boson. However in the expanded form of the standard model of particle physics where Goldstone bosons and Faddeev-Popov ghosts are explicitly shown, like [here](https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/sites/default/files/images/standard/sml.png), they are absent. Did I missed something about those terms or is there a way to suppress them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These terms vanish by integration by parts due the $R_\xi$ gauge choice $G^a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\xi}}(\partial_\mu A^{a,\mu}-\xi g F^a_{\ \ i} \chi_i)$ in the partition function :
\begin{equation}
Z\propto \int \mathcal{D} A \mathcal{D} \chi \exp \left[ i \int d^4 x \left( \mathcal{L}[A,\chi] -\frac{1}{2} G^a G^a \right) \right]\det \left( \frac{\delta G}{\delta \alpha} \right)
\end{equation}
Where one has expanded the scalar field about the expectation values: $\phi_i=\phi_{0i}+\chi_i$

Answer (score 0):

It's probably implicitly in the second section, as $\phi^0-H=v$.